# Exponent of $\Bbb Z$ in tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, tensor-products, abelian-groups, direct-sum

In computing
$$
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\op}{\oplus}
\Bigl( \Z^2 \op (\Z/6\Z) \op (\Z/126\Z) \Bigr) 
\otimes_\Z 
\Bigl( \Z \op (\Z/45\Z) \op (\Z/495\Z) \Bigr),
$$
do I get as exponent of $\Bbb Z$ in the product, $3$ or $2$? The ring $\Bbb Z$ should be the identity element so I think $2$, but distributivity says:

is it $\Bbb Z ^2 \otimes \Bbb Z= (\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z)\otimes \Bbb Z$

or

is it $\Bbb Z ^2 \otimes \Bbb Z = (\Bbb Z \otimes \Bbb Z)\otimes \Bbb Z$?

Comment: The usual interpretation of exponents in the context of abelian groups is of repeated direct sum, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}^2 = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SammyBlack Then I guess th answer t my question is 2

Answer (score 1):

Exponents are pretty much never used like this to denote "powers" with respect to the tensor product.  If you wanted to write $\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}$ as a "power", the standard way to do that would be $\mathbb{Z}^{\otimes 2}$ with the little $\otimes$ in the exponent to indicate you mean a tensor power.

Instead, if there is no context that indicates otherwise, an exponent on any sort of algebraic structure normally indicates a power with respect to the Cartesian product, so $\mathbb{Z}^2$ means $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.  In the case of abelian groups if the exponent is finite, this is equivalent to a direct sum as well.